# How to Update last 3 columns of a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, join, temp-tables

```
ReqId             RespId         NAME            Part   Type   Base
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
674508621DF6    D5830288F5C2    00000233A   NULL    NULL    NULL
C356C1E03784    D5830288F5C2    00000233A   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

When I am running the following query with out **Stored Procedure Part** I am getting the above Result. Now I want to update the SP using return values from an SP.

```
DECLARE @TempTable Table(
ReqId varchar(255),
RespId  varchar(255),
Name varchar(255),
Part bit,
Type bit,
Base bit)

INSERT  @TempTable (ReqId ,RespId  ,Name)
Select * from DistributesSystemsView DSV
join MyDomain MD with(nolock) on MD.MyDomainID = DSV.MyDomainId
where DSV.LotOperationSegmentResponseId=@LotOpSegRespId
```

**Stored Procedure Part**
I should be able to update `part,Type and Base` columns using following SP which takes MD.DomainId as a parameter from above join Statement

```
 INSERT  @TempTable(Part,Type,Base)
 EXECUTE [SOADB].[dbo].[spLocal_AnotherSpl] MD.MyDomainID


Select * from @TempTable
```

Comment: What is the output of the stored procedure? If it only returns Part, Type, and Base, how does it know which record to fill out since the records only have ReqId, RespId, and Name filled in? You need something to join on.

Comment: `update the SP using return values from an SP` what does it mean? It is not clear what you want.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri,spLocal_AnotherSp returns Part,Type and Base . Now I want to update the Temp table using the values returned from SP.

Comment: In temp table there 10 rows, sp returns 15 or 2 rows. Which rows to update?

Comment: @Simsons, the SP needs to return the ReqId, RespId, and/or Name (whatever the "key" is). Otherwise it has no way of joining to the original temptable to know which rows to update. It's impossible unless there is a common key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can try something like this.

1. Add a new column `MyDomainID` to your `@TempTable`
2. Insert data into `@TempTable` as before
3. Have another table `@TempTable2` which stores the data you get from your procedure for a specific `@MyDomainID`
4. Run your update of `@TempTable` after joining with `@TempTable2`
5. Rinse and repeat Steps 3 and 4 if required for different values of `@MyDomainID`

**Query**

```
DECLARE @TempTable Table(
MyDomainID  varchar(255),
ReqId varchar(255),
RespId  varchar(255),
Name varchar(255),
Part bit,
Type bit,
Base bit);

INSERT  @TempTable (MyDomainId,ReqId ,RespId  ,Name)
Select DSV.MyDomainId,ReqId ,RespId  ,Name from DistributesSystemsView DSV
join MyDomain MD with(nolock) on MD.MyDomainID = DSV.MyDomainId
where DSV.LotOperationSegmentResponseId=@LotOpSegRespId



DECLARE @TempTable2 Table(
Part bit,
Type bit,
Base bit)

INSERT  @TempTable(Part,Type,Base)
EXECUTE [SOADB].[dbo].[spLocal_AnotherSpl] @MyDomainID

UPDATE T
SET Part = Temp2.Part ,
Type = Temp2.Type,
Base = Temp2.Base
FROM @TempTable T
CROSS JOIN @TempTable2 Temp2
WHERE T.MyDomainID = @MyDomainID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the procedure [SOADB].[dbo].[spLocal_AnotherSpl] returns only 3 i.e columns (Part,Type,Base) & @MyDomainID (int) is a single parameter to be passed to the sp..

```
Declare @query varchar(max)
Set @query = 'EXEC [SOADB].[dbo].[spLocal_AnotherSpl] ' + ltrim(rtrim( str ( @MyDomainID )))

INSERT  @TempTable(Part,Type,Base)
Exec( @query )
```

If a single parameter cannot be passed, Pass a table type or write your query inside the other sp..

Answer (score -1):

You could make `Part, Type, Base` output parameters of the SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spMyProc
@MyDomainID int,
@part bit output, 
@type bit output, 
@base bit output
AS
...
```

Then declare and send the variables to the SP:

```
DECLARE @part bit, @type bit, @base bit
EXECUTE [SOADB].[dbo].[spLocal_AnotherSpl] MD.MyDomainID, @part output, @type output, @base output
```

Finally you can do whatever you need to do with the values `@part @type @base`

Comment: That assumes the SP only returns one row. His sample seems to show two rows.